# combine two methods in Java together in this Java code

Tags: java, frequency

I want combine the two methods Just some error in my document parser, frequencyCounter and parseFiles thsi code.

I want all of frequencyCounter should be a function that should be executed from within parseFiles, and relevant information don't worry about the file's content should be passed to doSomething so that it knows what to print.

Right now I'm just keep messing up on how to put these two methods together, please give some advices

this is my main class:

```
public class Yolo {
    public static void frodo() throws Exception {
        int n; // number of keywords
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("number of keywords : ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("give the testword : ");
            String testWord = scan.next();
            System.out.println(testWord);

            File document = new File("path//to//doc1.txt");
            boolean check = true;

            try {
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(document);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
                String strLine;
                strLine = br.readLine();

                // Read File Line By Line

                int count = 0;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    // check to see whether testWord occurs at least once in the
                    // line of text
                    check = strLine.toLowerCase().contains(testWord.toLowerCase());

                    if (check) {
                        // get the line
                        String[] lineWords = strLine.split("\\s+");
                        // System.out.println(strLine);
                        count++;
                    }

                }
                System.out.println(testWord + "frequency: " + count);

                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are your CosineSimilarity() and TfIdf()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below gives you this output:

```
Professor frequency: 54
engineering frequency: 188
data frequency: 2
mining frequency: 2
research frequency: 9
```

Though this is only for doc1, you've to add a loop to iterate on all the 5 documents.

```
public class yolo {
    public static void frodo() throws Exception {

        String[] keywords = { "Professor" , "engineering" , "data" , "mining" , "research"};
        for(int i=0; i< keywords.length; i++){

        String testWord = keywords[i];
        File document = new File("path//to//doc1.txt");
        boolean check = true;

        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(document);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            strLine = br.readLine();

            // Read File Line By Line

            int count = 0;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // check to see whether testWord occurs at least once in the
                // line of text
                check = strLine.toLowerCase().contains(testWord.toLowerCase());

                if (check) {
                    // get the line
                    String[] lineWords = strLine.split("\\s+");
                    count++;
                }

            }
            System.out.println(testWord + "frequency: " + count);

            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

hope this helps!

Comment: @alaye thank you sir, also do I add this class into my main java class or document parser java?

Comment: to your main, add this "yolo.frodo();"
you don't need your frequency counter and parser anymore

Comment: just delete those two methods!